# How to ask a question on Stack Overflow, step by step procedure

Tags: discussion, questions

I ask a question related to programming, on meta stack overflow, but my question was closed as I question on meta side. So I want to question on stack overflow, not in meta stack over flow. But when I click on same "ask question" button on stack overflow, the page with a search box comes, and I can not go ahead from here. This page also contains

- how to ask
- do your home work
- do specific
- do relevant to other and so on...

Please help me how can I ask a programming related question step by step?

How can I put a file with my question?

Comment: Well, you asked a question here, didn't you? The process on SO is exactly the same. What do you mean by a "Search Box"? Grab a screenshot perhaps and show us?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) should take you to the "Ask Question" page...try clicking it and see if it works.

Answer (score 6):

There are step by step instructions on the main Stack Overflow site.

Click on the link on the top right that says "[Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)", then check the sidebar for help. A few brief clues are given, but more importantly there are links to the FAQ and other important documentation on exactly how to answer.

You may not attach a file to your question. Do your best to explain it in words and include relevant bits of code in the body of the question.